# How to add the number of words in a list/string to a counter?

Tags: python, while-loop, counter

I'm creating a spellchecker program which returns all incorrectly spelled words from a string input or a text file. I would like the program to add up the number of incorrectly spelled words, and print it as a stat.

I can't seem to figure out how to count the number of words in a list, and add it to the counter.

```py
errorCount = 0

while True:
    try:
        selection = int(input("Would you like to enter a string (1), open a text file (2) or Quit (0) ?"))
        if selection==1:
            String = input("Please enter your string: ")
            dictionaryList = readDictionaryFile(dictionaryFile)
            stringList = readString(String)
            errorList = findErrors(dictionaryList, stringList)
            printErrors(errorList)
            errorCount = errorCount + errorList.count()
```

Comment: what format is the errorList in. is it a string list or dictionary

Comment: It is a string list, with its elements being the words which aren't found in the dictionary list

Comment: you could call len(errorList) this will return the number of elements inside the list

Comment: then i can do errorCount = errorCount + len(errorList)? Thank you a lot

Comment: just for future clarity ill put this in the answers

Answer (score 0):

Using len(errorList) will return the number of elements (errors) in the list

Comment: for some reason, when i print len(errorList), it doesnt print a number :/ i've removed the errorCount also

Comment: what is getting printed to the screen

Comment: when i run it and type in a incorrectly spelled word, it prints "the incorrectly spelled words are: aksjkasj" with no other information, then it returns to the selection again

Comment: could you post the print statment please

Comment: in your print statment there is no errorList included perhaps add a second print statment along the lines of print("there were " + len(errorList) )

Answer (score 0):

```
def printErrors(errorList):
    print ("The incorrectly spelled words are: ")
    for words in errorList:
        print(words)
```

thats the print statement, sorry

Comment: your doing for words in error list this will tell you all the words in the list but will not output the number of them